# Undefined variable, nodejs, json to program variable

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, undefined, visual-web-developer

I decided to save data the dirty way to a .json file. For some reason, when I run my index.js file which runs other modules I have written, it says that a particular variable I initialized in a separate module is undefined (one I was hoping to reference from json). The structure of my program is the standard index file that loads functions from modules I have written and executes them via endpoints.

.json File

```
{"blocks":[{"GENESIS_DATA":{"timestamp":1,"lastHash":"v01d","hash":"?M=(((Position-1)=>ter)=>sen)=>non?","difficulty":20,"nonce":0,"data":[]}}]}
```

I want to take the first index of this array named GENESIS_DATA and use it as an array in my program...

relevant code from blockchain index (not the file I execute for the program to run)

```
const { REWARD_INPUT, MINING_REWARD, GENESIS_DATA } = require('../config');
const fs = require('fs');
const jsonRoute = '/home/main/public_html/Cypher-Network/CDSM/CDSM.json';

class Blockchain {
  constructor() {
fs.readFile(jsonRoute, 'utf-8', function(err, data) {
    if (err) throw err;

    this.jsonChain = JSON.parse(data);
    const genesis = jsonChain.blocks[0];
});
    this.chain = [genesis];
  }

/*Alot more code down here but let's assume that the bracket for class Blockchain is completed*/
}
```

error log

```
/home/main/public_html/Cypher-Network/blockchain/index.js:32
    this.chain = [genesis]; //we are taking the first element of the json file (genesis block)
                  ^

ReferenceError: genesis is not defined
    at new Blockchain (/home/main/public_html/Cypher-Network/blockchain/index.js:32:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/main/public_html/Cypher-Network/index.js:28:20)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1158:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1178:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1002:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:901:14)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:74:12)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:18:47
main@goldengates.club [~/public_html/Cypher-Network]#
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, the constant genesis is local to the callback, so it is getting destroyed just after the callback has finished running.
Also even if the constant was declared outside the callback, remember that fs.readFile is asynchronous, so while readFile is reading the file containing the data, the constant genesis will have already been set to undefined.

Comment: I just realized that when I set jsonChain to const it does not become undefined. I was using the "this" keyword in an awkward way

Comment: the jsonChain also was not destroyed it seems since it passed as a valid parameter for chain array just outside the callback after setting it to constant and referencing it in genesis

Comment: Okey, I'll advise you to add an edit to your post showing the correct code

Comment: ok, so after tampering some more, I realized that I did not fix it and thank god for that because of the scope thing you were talking about. So how would I be able to set a variable in that callback to the json object without having it being undefined when I call it out of the callback?

Comment: I tried ```global.genesis = jsonChain.blocks[0].GENESIS_DATA;``` but it still gave me undefined, then I tried to global jsonChain aswell and it gave me this error ```undefined
listening at localhost:3000
/home/main/public_html/Cypher-Network/blockchain/index.js:19
global.genesis = jsonChain.blocks[0].GENESIS_DATA;
TypeError: Cannot read property 'blocks' of undefined
    at /home/main/public_html/Cypher-Network/blockchain/index.js:19:29
    at FSReqCallback.readFileAfterClose [as oncomplete] (internal/fs/read_file_context.js:63:3)
main@goldengates.club [~/public_html/Cypher-Network]#```